# How to store column value in Comma Separated row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with one requirement and need some expert input.

**Requirement**

Employee will have 3 types of phones types like Home, Pager, Cell. I have a table called **EmpPhone** and whenever phones numbers are entered in UI this will stored in a different row.

So if I take EmpID = 744, currently he has 4 phone numbers(check pic)

[image]

Earlier we were not sure that UI can handle Same type phone numbers in this case its Type = 0. I could able to move these 3 row data to single row which is what I needed.

[image]

here is where I stuck, since UI can contain multiple phone types of any numbers, current data is showing only first data and hides other, so I need Type 0 phone numbers to accommodate in single **HomePhone** cell.

I even browsed and could able to get the values in single cell however I was not able to implement same code in actual stored procedure.

THIS IS WHAT I DID

```
DECLARE @HomePhoneNumbers varchar(MAX)
SET @HomePhoneNumbers = ''
SELECT @HomePhoneNumbers = @HomePhoneNumbers + CONVERT(varchar, PhoneNumber) 
+ ',' 
FROM EmpPhone
where EmployeeID=744 and EmpPhone.Type =0

-- Remove last comma
SELECT LEFT(@HomePhoneNumbers, LEN(@HomePhoneNumbers) - 1)
```

Which gives me what i need 
[image]

if you observe the code I have hardcoded employeeID and I cannot do it actual StorProc since EmployeeID is not passed as parameter. here is my sample code snippet.

```
SELECT
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EmpPhone.Type = 0 THEN ISNULL(EmpPhone.PhoneNumber,'') END) HomePhone
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EmpPhone.Type = 2 THEN ISNULL(EmpPhone.PhoneNumber,'') END) Cell
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EmpPhone.Type = 5 THEN ISNULL(EmpPhone.PhoneNumber,'') END) Pager
    ,E.EmployeeID

    From 
    //JOINING FEW TABLES
```

Let me know if I am clear enough.

SOLUTION

Guess what I implemented that without CTE, but your answer helped me to solve :)

```
SELECT
EmployeeID,
Type,
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
        ', ' + PhoneNumber
    FROM EmpPhone E
    WHERE E.EmployeeID = T.EmployeeID AND E.Type = T.Type
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, ''
) AS Phones
INTO #PhoneNumbers
    FROM EmpPhone AS T
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, Type

    Select
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN PH.Type = 0 THEN ISNULL(PH.Phones,'') END) HomePhone
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN PH.Type = 2 THEN ISNULL(PH.Phones,'') END) Cell
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN PH.Type = 5 THEN ISNULL(PH.Phones,'') END) Pager
```

I just used temptable and added that to joins, worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to [concatenate string using SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) coming from different rows into a single value
Please check referrred tutorial and try following SQL Select statement

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    Type,
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT
            ', ' + PhoneNumber
        FROM EmpPhone e
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID and
              e.Type = t.Type
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) As Phones
FROM EmpPhone as t
Group By EmployeeID, Type
```

I hope it helps

Referring to your first comment, I modified above query into a CTE expression and added an aggregation logic as follows

```
;with cte as (
SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    Type,
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT
            ', ' + PhoneNumber
        FROM EmpPhone e
        WHERE e.EmployeeID = t.EmployeeID and
              e.Type = t.Type
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
        ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
        ), 1, 1, ''
    ) As Phones
FROM EmpPhone as t
Group By EmployeeID, Type
)
select
    EmployeeID,
    MAX(case when type = 0 then phones end) as 'HOME',
    MAX(case when type = 2 then phones end) as 'PAGER',
    MAX(case when type = 5 then phones end) as 'CELL'
from cte
group by 
    EmployeeID
```

The output is now as follows

[image]

Comment: I tried this as well, at present your code is showing phone numbers under Phones, can I move those phone numbers to column based on Type, like what I did in my CASE statement?

Comment: I understand it now better, I added an other SELECT with CTE and aggregation section, I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you Eralper for your valuable input, I could able to solve this using temp table, however will accept your answer which helped me to crack this.have updated my answer under SOLUTION.